# Adding condition to mapping for child collection in Entity Framework 6 similar to NHibernate's "where"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, entity-framework-6

In NHibernate, there is a `where` mapping that allows you to specify a condition on a property mapping that affects how it is pulled from the database. For example, if I wanted to implement a soft delete and exclude all deleted items from a set, I could map it like so:

#### FluentNHibernate

```cs
// in class ParentMap : ClassMap
HasMany(x => x.Children).Where("IsDeleted = 0");
```

#### Hbm.Xml

```xml
<class name="Parent" table="[Parents]">
    <bag cascade="all" lazy="true" name="Children" where="IsDeleted = 0">
        <!-- rest of map here -->
    </bag>
</class>
```

Is there anything similar in Entity Framework 6?

The closest thing I found was a library called **[EntityFramework.Filters](https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters/)**, which allows you to add global filters for properties, but it doesn't seem to work when that property is a collection.

---

To give a better example of why a mapping like this is necessary, let's say I have a class that has a collection of objects that have a recursive child entity relationship (i.e., a collection of objects of the same type). They follow this basic structure:

```cs
public class ReportOutline
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<OutlineItem> OutlineItems { get; set; }
}

public class OutlineItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long ReportOutlineId { get; set; }
    public long? ParentOutlineItemId { get; set; }    

    public virtual ReportOutline ReportOutline { get; set; }
    public virtual OutlineItem ParentOutlineItem { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<OutlineItem> OutlineItems { get; set; }
}
```

And these are mapped with the EF fluent API like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ReportOutline>()
    .HasKey(o => o.Id)
    .HasMany(o => o.OutlineItems)
    .WithRequired(i => i.ReportOutline)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.OutlineId);

modelBuilder.Entity<OutlineItem>()
    .HasKey(p => p.Id)
    .HasMany(p => p.OutlineItems)
    .WithOptional(c => c.ParentOutlineItem)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentOutlineItemId);
```

This produces the correct database structure, and my records look fine. Here's an example of what the `OutlineItems` table would look like with two items on a `ReportOutline`, if one had two child items (four altogether):

```
Id    Name           ReportOutlineId    ParentOutlineItemId
1     Introduction   1                  NULL
2     Pets           1                  NULL
3     Cats           1                  2
4     Dogs           1                  2
```

When the `ReportOutline` gets loaded through the `DbContext`, however, since `ReportOutlineId` matched the outline's `Id`, the `ReportOutline.OutlineItems` is getting populated with all four items. This results in the sub-items appearing both under the parent items and the main outline itself:

```
Title:  My Report
Author: valverij

I.  Introduction  (Id: 1)
II. Pets          (Id: 2)
    A. Cats       (Id: 3)
    B. Dogs       (Id: 4)
III. Cats         (Id: 3) <--- Duplicated
IV.  Dogs         (Id: 4) <--- Duplicated
```

Now, if I were using NHibernate with FluentNhibernate, I could specify a `where` condition on the entity mapping, so that `ReportOutline.OutlineItems` *only* pulls parent items:

```cs
// in ReportOutlineMap
HasMany(x => x.OutlineItems).Where("ParentOutlineItemId IS NULL");
```

Without that, I would have to remember to *only* access `ReportOutline` objects through a pre-written query that explicitly deals with the `OutlineItem` collection.

Comment: Confused...why does OutlineItem contain a collection of OutLineItems? It looks like ReportOutLine contains a collection of collections...is that what you want?

Comment: No, it is not a collection of collections. A `ReportOutline` can have multiple `OutlineItems`. Each one has information about itself. Each of those `OutlineItems` can also have one or more `OutlineItems` that falls under it (see the example output).

Comment: OK...I think I get it...you want a ReportOutLine and the ReportOutLine should have ReportOutLineItems and then each ReportOutLineItem can then have, in addition to a name and Id, it's own set of items? Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that's right. If you've ever made an outline for a speech or a report (or made a to-do list with sub-items), it's the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an "RootOutlineItems" property to the ReportOutline class that filters for you, then call that when you want just the 1st level:

```
public class ReportOutline
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<OutlineItem> OutlineItems { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OutlineItem> RootOutlineItems { 
        get {
            return OutlineItems.Where(p=> p.ParentOutlineItem == null);
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to make the OutlineItem's ReportOutline nullable, and only ever set *either* the ReportOutline or the ParentOutlineItem property, but that's a little iffy, plus you'd have to navigate the tree if you ever want *all* the items.

Comment: NOTE: The downside to the above RootLevelItems is that you won't be able to save changes, you'd have to add items to the normal OutlineItems property.